# Python, command line argument parsing

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

How do you accept/parse command line arguments for a py file that has no class? Here is what I have inside my file test.py:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
```

How do I get the arguments when the file is executed via command line? I call it via:

```
python test.py <arg1>
```

and obviously want the value of "arg1".

Comment: I did and couldn't find much other than libraries that I don't want to import.

Comment: When you search for `argv python`. first link on Google is your answer

Comment: @EknathIyer That's all well and good, but what if you don't know to google for `argv`? This is perfectly appropriate.

Comment: @Eknath: Really? How am I suppose to know what argv is if I've never come across it before?

Comment: How aboout: `python commad line argument` most results on the first page point to the right answer, *with examples*

Comment: @EknathIyer See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers. Google should lead here. This may not be a great question, but the fact that you can Google the answer _if you know the right search terms_ doesn't mean it's not appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look no further than [`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.argv), which is a list containing all arguments passed to the program.

Comment: Thank you sir, I figured it was something easy like this. For some reason I couldn't get a google search to provide me with this.

Comment: Remember "argv". That's standard computer speak for the arguments passed to any program. Historically it is short for "argument vector", a vector being mostly equivalent to what Python calls a `list`.

Answer (score 5):

```
try:
    arg = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print "No argument specified."
    sys.exit(1)
```